# How to save one existing model as another existing model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

If I want to load an existing model instance and then save it's copy as a new one - I can use `replicate()`.

But if I want to create model instance (or load existing one) and then save it replacing another existing one - how can I do it?

So far, I do it by changing model's `id` and `exists` properties (to make it save instance to a new or existing record in DB), but it seems like a hack and I feel like there should be a cleaner way to do it.. does it?

**UPD**

I have quite peculiar user preferences system in one of my projects.

- preferences may exist "for user", "for user role" and "default (for all)"
- when we load current user's preferences, we can get exactly "this user's" preference, or "this user's role's preferense" (if user's one doesnt exist), or "default one" or even "new one" if nothing from above exists.
- when we save them - we must save it only as "this user's" preferences, no matter which of above we've read it as.
- and because multiple sessions of one user may exist at the same time, even if we loaded preference as new one, when saving we may find out that it already exist (because it was created by other session under the same user).
- and we should handle all this stuff from within Model's methods, according to current project's desing.

For now it looks like this (not exactly, I've just reproduced the main idea here):

```
class SomePreferencesClass extends Model {
    public static function getForCurrentUser(): self {
        $existingUserPref = self::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        if(!empty($existingUserPref)) {
            return $existingUserPref;
        }

        $existingRolePref = self::where('user_role_id', Auth::user()?->user_role_id)->first();
        if(!empty($existingRolePref)) {
            return $existingRolePref->forCurrentUser();
        }

        $existingDefaultPref = self::where('user_id', null)->where('user_role_id', null)->first();
        if(!empty($existingDefaultPref)) {
            return $existingDefaultPref->forCurrentUser();;
        }

        return new self()->forCurrentUser();
    }

    public function saveForCurrentUser() {
        DB::transaction(fn() => {
            $existingUserPref = self::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
            if(!empty($existingUserPref)) {
                $this->changeId($existingUserPref->id);
            }

            // ... do other stuff

            $this->save();
        });
    }


    private function forCurrentUser() {
        $this->user_role_id = null;
        $this->user_id = Auth::id();
        $this->changeId(null); // detach from existing instance

        return $this;
    }


    private function changeId($id) {
        // mark relations as need-to-be-cloned if id has been changed
        $this->dirtyRelations = $id !== $this->id; 

        // reattach this model to another instance (new or existing)
        $this->exists = !empty($id); 
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}
```

But changing `id` and `exists` I feel like invading the underhood that I better avoid touching by doing it some mode appropriate way instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate you problem more ?

Comment: @xenooooo okay, updated the post above

Answer (score 1):

"*and we should handle all this stuff from within Model's methods*" - this is not that great since in your code you are linking the data layer (models) to the http layer (requests, sessions). What happens when you want to do the same thing via a console command or offload the work to a job? None of these have a current authenticated user, that you model now depends on.

Anyhow I think this implementation makes more sense, you can optimize `getForUser` a bit to run only one query and not 3 for each call.

```php
class SomePreferencesClass extends Model
{
    public static function getForUser(User $user): SomePreferencesClass
    {
        $existingUserPref = self::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        if($existingUserPref) {
            return $existingUserPref;
        }

        $existingRolePref = self::where('user_role_id', $user->user_role_id)->first();
        if($existingRolePref) {
            return self::buildUserPreferences($user, $existingRolePref);
        }

        $existingDefaultPref = self::whereNull('user_id')->whereNull('user_role_id')->first();
        if($existingDefaultPref) {
            return self::buildUserPreferences($user, $existingDefaultPref);
        }

        return self::buildUserPreferences($user);
    }

    public function saveForUser(User $user)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            
            if ($this->user_id == $user->id) {
                $this->save();
                $pref = $this;
            } else {
                $userPreferences = $this->replicate(['id', 'user_id', 'user_role_id']);
                $userPreferences->user_id = $user->id;

                $pref = SomePreferencesClass::query()
                    ->updateOrCreate(
                        ['user_id' => $user->id],
                        $userPreferences->toArray()
                    );
            }

            DB::commit();

            return $pref;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return null; // rethrow or however you want to handle
        }
    }


    public static function buildUserPreferences(User $user, ?SomePreferencesClass $preference = null): SomePreferencesClass
    {
        $userPreferences = $preference ? $preference->replicate(['id', 'user_id', 'user_role_id']) : new SomePreferencesClass;

        $userPreferences->user_id = $user->id;

        return $userPreferences;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, i see your point, but as for me it makes the logic way more confusing: after calling saveForUser on a model instance we actually dont know if this instance was saved, or it just cloned itself into another one under the hood... if I have to sync relations after saving - I will have to re-read pref for user, or do smth else to be sure that I operate just saved one.... so what I tried to achieve is to make $this instance be representation of exactly just saved DB record after saving.

Comment: what about "linking the data layer (models) to the http layer (requests, sessions)" - do you mean my using Auth::id() to determine current user? If so - yep, I agree, passing user_id explicity, as you did, would be a better way.

Comment: first of all it is normal to reload a relation after you have changed a foreign key, your db should be your single source of truth. however for a simple case like this you can set the relation yourself. return the saved model from `saveForUser` and do something like `$user->setRelation('preference', $pref->saveForUser($user));`

Comment: also if you are not running multiple queries, you don't need the transaction/try-catch